# Why did my ceramic coated loaf pan turn brown?

Tags: baking, equipment, ceramic

I used ceramic a coated loaf pan and the inside color which was white, changed to brown, as if it has burnt, is that normal?

Comment: Welcome Buthaina - can you tell us give us the details on how you used the pan?

Comment: What were you cooking in it? Is it an even brown all up the sides, or more splotchy; is it where the food/loaf was in contact with the pan or not?